# Force OpenGL rendering to run always on same (Q)Thread in Qt

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, opengl

I created an application with a Qt GUI that does image processing. For one part of the computations, OpenGL is used to render a transformed image (off-screen). Everything worked fine. However, I did all the heavy processing when a button was clicked in the GUI thread. Since computations take several seconds, the GUI then became non-responsive.

Fortunately Qt already includes a Thread libray (`QThread`, `QtConcurrent` etc.). Now I just use `QtConcurrent::run()` and a `QFutureWatcher<cv::Mat>` to do the computations asynchronously with a callback function. The problem is that during the computations, the OpenGL function is called multiple times and can now run on different threads for consecutive button clicks. If the rendering is done on a different thread than on the one OpenGL was initialized, OpenGL renders nothing (black screen). Of course this depends on the thread handling of Qt.

So my question is: is there an easy solution using the current setup (Qt threads and OpenGL) without additional libraries etc. to enforce the rendering to be run always on the same thread.

I know that there's a method `QObject::moveToThread()`, but I don't know exactly how to use it in this case. The OpenGL stuff does not contain any Qt-related code or functions at all. So how could I solve this problem?

And I also couldn't figure out if a certain `QThread` always uses the same underlying native thread. Is this the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one [approach](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/87747/#msg470626). You create a thread which lives as long as you need and you add jobs to it. You could replace QThread or use std::thread.

Comment: Thanks, I already considered a similar solution. I could initialize OpenGL by adding it as a task to the worker and then always add the rendering tasks to this worker. I just don't know if it's a good idea to mix up this solution with QThreads... The problem with just replacing thread with QThread in the example could be that QThread is only a wrapper for native threads (as far as I understand, it could also be that it chooses the GUI thread as underlying thread).
But I will try this and mark the question as accepted if there are no other answers :)

Comment: You can take a look also at some more approaches described here -- https://github.com/troyane/lambdaConcurrent